# rkhunter error message, how to fix?

Tags: linux, debian-squeeze, rkhunter

I am receiving the following errors from rkhunter. I have recently upgraded my server from lenny to squeeze and this may have caused the problem. How do I fix this or hide the error messages?

```
Warning: The modules file '/proc/modules' is missing.
Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
         /dev/shm/network/ifstate: ASCII text
Warning: Hidden directory found: /dev/.udev
```

I also not get a second email: `Please inspect this machine, because it may be infected.` Please can anybody point me in the right direction to find the cause of these errors?

Comment: You can disable the test loaded_modules (not os_specific).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, they are only **warnings**, not errors.

```
Warning: The modules file '/proc/modules' is missing.
```

`rkhunter` is trying to check the kernel modules, but it cannot because the file `/proc/modules` doesn't exist. You can disable the test by changing the below line:

```
DISABLE_TESTS="suspscan hidden_procs deleted_files packet_cap_apps"
```

to:

```
DISABLE_TESTS="suspscan hidden_procs deleted_files packet_cap_apps os_specific"
```

About the second warning:

```
Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
         /dev/shm/network/ifstate: ASCII text
```

If `/dev/shm/network/ifstate` is a known good file, you can white-list it by adding the following line in `/etc/rkhunter.conf`:

```
ALLOWDEVFILE=/dev/shm/network/ifstate
```

About the third line:

```
Warning: Hidden directory found: /dev/.udev
```

Similar to above, to avoid this warning, you can reconfigure `rkhunter` to ignore this directory:

```
ALLOWHIDDENDIR=/dev/.udev
```